# matlab engine has no attribute 'shareEngine'

Tags: python, matlab

Today I have tried to run matlab engine from python script.
I installed Matlab API for python step by step using official instructions from this site:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html

But when I try make my matlab engine instance as shared instance by using method shareEngine('Engine_name') (see code):

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
matlab.engine.shareEngine('Engine_1')
names = matlab.engine.find_matlab()
print(names)
eng.quit()
```

Then i receive error from console output:

```
    C:\Users\rpawlak\Google Drive\python_radio>python matlab_python.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matlab_python.py", line 4, in <module>
    matlab.engine.shareEngine('Engine_1')
AttributeError: module 'matlab.engine' has no attribute 'shareEngine'
```

I do not understand why I receive this error, i follow by official adi documentation form matlab site:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/connect-python-to-running-matlab-session.html

Is documentation is outdated or i have outdated matlab version? 
My matlab is: R2018a 9.4.0

Regards,
Robert

Comment: From the second link it says you need to call `matlab.engine.shareEngine` _from_ matlab

Comment: Yes, you re right. Did you mabye know how to run matlab engine as backgorund process? When i trying to execute: matlab -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -automation -r "run("matlab.engine.shareEngine");" then i receive matlab console window, but closing this window provide closing also matlab backgorund process. Have u any idea how to sole this issue?

Comment: Because from this instruction I can assume there is no possibility to make shared instance of engine from python level.

Comment: You have a version of MATLAB that is older than the documentation you are reading. There are two releases of MATLAB every year, so you are 7 releases behind the docs you are reading. Either upgrade, or read the documentation that comes with your version of MATLAB.

Comment: That said, `matlab.engine.shareEngine` was introduced in MATLAB R2015b, so you should have access to it. DavidG is right, you must run the command inside your MATLAB session before connecting to it from Python. It has a very specific use case. What is your use case? Why do you need a shared session? (I’m asking because it’ll help form a useful answer other than “don’t do that”).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to call in MATLAB session `matlab.engine.shareEngine`
and don't use `matlab.engine.shareEngine('Engine_1')` in Python

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()

names = matlab.engine.find_matlab()
print(names)
eng.quit()
```